# Apache Nifi GetTwitter

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a simple question, as I am new to NiFi.

I have a GetTwitter processor set up and configured (assuming correctly). I have the Twitter Endpoint set to Sample Endpoint. I run the processor and it runs, but nothing happens. I get no input/output

How do I troubleshoot what it is doing (or in this case not doing)?

Comment: I have the same problem; you can tail the logs found in `NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` to see why exactly its failing. In my case its a IO InvalidArgument exception.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things you might look at:

- What activity does the processor show?  You can look at the metrics to see if anything has been attempted (Tasks/Time) as well as if it succeeded (Out)
  [image]
- Stop the downstream processor temporarily to make any output FlowFiles visible in the connection queue.
- Are there errors? Typically these appear in the top-left corner as a yellow icon
- Are there related messages in the logs/nifi-app.log file?

It might also help us help you if you describe the GetTwitter Property settings a bit more.  Can you share a screenshot (minus keys)?

Answer (score 0):

In my case its because there are two sensitive values set. According to the documentation when a sensitive value is set, the `nifi.properties` file's `nifi.sensitive.props.key` value must be set - it is an empty string by default using HortonWorks DataPlatform distribution. I set this to some random string (literally `random_STRING` but you can use anything) and re-created my process from the template and it began working.

Answer (score 0):

In general I suppose this topic can be debugged by setting the loglevel to DEBUG. 
However, in my case the issue was resolved more easily:

I just set up a new cluster, and decided to copy all twitter keys and secrets to notepad first.

It turns out that despite carefully copying the keys from twitter, one of them had **a leading tab**. When pasting directly into the GetTwitter processer, this would not show, but fortunately it showed up in notepad and I was able to remove it and make this work.